# Redirecting input and output files on Unix and C++ using stdio

Tags: c++, linux, unix, stdio

I need to do this:

```
$ ./compiledprog.x < inputValues > outputFile
```

so that I read from the file `inputValues` which for our case might just be `\n` separated `int` values or whatever.   Then anything `printf()`'d goes into `outputFile`.  But what's this called, technically speaking, and where can I find a demo of doing this.

Comment: This is done by the shell, not by the program being executed. The program is completely ignorant of this behaviour.

Comment: okay yes this is the specs for project that it should run at shell like that but wutdo

Comment: When you do `./compiledprog.x < inputValues` the shell automatically reads `inputValues` and puts it in the `stdin` of your program. If you do `> outputFile` it automatically redirects the `stdout` of your program to `outputFile`. You don't have to do anything in your program. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: okay so how do i get the stdin values in C++ then so I can parse them

Comment: Like you normally would: `cin >> stuff`

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Technically speaking, the program could know if its stdin is a terminal or not, so it _could_ know if a redirection or pipe occurred, e.g. with isatty(fileno(stdin));

Comment: Note that in C++, you should normally avoid using `<stdio.h>` and use the `<iostream>` facilities instead since they are type-safe.  (And yes, I revised the title which now begs the question: 'What is redirection called?', but there were no pipes involved, so the title with 'Piping' instead was also sub-optimal.)

Comment: @Karolos yes you're right, I stated it poorly. I meant it _can_ be completely ignorant of the redirection.

Comment: Strictly, the shell doesn't read the `inputValues` file; it opens it for reading, and arranges for it to be the standard input of the program, but leaves all the actual reading to the program.  Similarly with the output file; the shell opens it for writing and connects it to the standard output of the program, but does not itself write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others, it's input/output redirection.

Here's an example program that would copy the standard input to the standard output, in your example copy the contents from inputValues to outputFile. Implement whatever logic you want in the program.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cerr;

#include <string>
using std::string;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        string str;

        // If cin is a terminal, print program usage
        if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) {
                cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " < inputValues > outputFile" << endl;
                return 1;
        }

        while( getline(cin, str) ) // As noted by Seth Carnegie, could also use cin >> str;
                cout << str << endl;

        return 0;
}
```

Note: this is quick and dirty code, which expects a well behaved file as input. A more detailed error checking could be added.

Comment: Usage messages should go to `cerr` so that they don't get confused with regular output.  That's the whole point of having `cerr` (and `stderr` in C).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, you're right. Thanks for correcting my laziness :) Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is called [I/O redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29).